# Call another ViewController without using storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I changed my button from calling another ViewController from Storyboard to download some stuff from a website using JSon. Now I need to call the very same ViewController after the code...

probably it is a simple stuff  but I didn't quite get it

thanks

Comment: you need to go back to your original view controller or what exactly do you mean by call the very same viewController after the code

Comment: It means that I removed the modal call from one view to another using Storyboard and need to do it from the code

Comment: take a look at this I think this is what you're after http://www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2 , this part `#pragma mark - PlayerDetailsViewControllerDelegate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that this is what you are looking for, but look at this.

Let's say you have two controllers, ViewController1 and ViewController2. After you are done with the JSON parsing in ViewController 1, let's say from [self finishedGetJSON], you could do this;

```
- (void) finishedGetJSON(yourargument*) arg {
    ViewController1 * screen = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourIdentifier"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:screen animated:YES];
```

Is that what you were looking for?